# EDIT:How to make go out from cycle and make task  recall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I'm using task to make Mass Pay API call to PayPal.

**EDIT:** If there are more than 250 recepients  I need to go out from cycle and call it again after finishing.

Here is my task:

```
    task :pay => :environment do
    clnt = HTTPClient.new
    i = 0;
    data = {    "METHOD" => "MassPay",
    ...}
    @users = User.all
    @users.each do |user|
       if i == 249 
            // call task again
       end
        data["L_EMAIL#{i}"] = "#{user.email}"
        data["L_AMT#{i}"] = "1.21"
        ...
        i+=1

        end
```

How I can make it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more functional way to do this would be to wrap everyting in a `in_groups_of` call. Guessing from your code, you would get something like:

```
task :pay => :environment do
  @users = User.all

  @users.in_groups_of(250, false).each do |group|
    clnt = HTTPClient.new
    data = {    "METHOD" => "MassPay",
      ...}

    group.each do |user|
      data["L_EMAIL#{i}"] = "#{user.email}"
      data["L_AMT#{i}"] = "1.21"
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Documentation is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Rake::Task['pay'].reenable
```

Comment: do you mean `if i == 249 
            Rake::Task['pay'].reenable 
       end
`?

Comment: I found that I'm a little bit fail in my logic. When there are 249 recepients I need to go out from the cycle and finish task.Then call it again. So I should use break operator ?

Comment: or somekind of `go to` operator